# Unknown gelocation / latitude longitude format

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, geo

I have geodata from a database in the form of e.g.:

565123.71392795,5930168.553

When looking for the general region of 56°,59° I can tell that this is completely wrong.
The location should be somewhere around 53.5°,10°
Is this even a valid geolocation format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the UTM Format or Universal Transverse Mercator format. As the Location is in Germany it should be:
32U565....,59301...

For further Information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system